# Launching phantomjs as a local Resource when using an Executable Jar

Tags: java, jar, resources

Need a little bit of help with this one. 
My goal is to have an executable jar file that takes a screen-capture of a webpage and works on both windows and linux machines. I have tried using html2image but the results from phantomjs were exponentially better.
I have code that looks like this:

```
RESOURCE_PATH = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources").getPath();

public static void main (String[] args) {    
    String url = args[1];
    String outFilePath = args[0];
    final String phantomjsHome = RESOURCE_PATH + "/phantomjs/";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(phantomjsHome + "phantomjs.exe", phantomjsRasterizeScript, url, outFilePath);
    Process process = pb.start();
    process.waitFor();

}
```

Now I have tests which assure me when I'm running this as a java application it works fine but when I build an executable jar I get an error. I have checked and double checked that the RESOURCE_FOLDER is pointing at the correct location. But when I run the jar using

`java -jar MyProject.jar "google.png" "https://google.com"`

I get a 

`java.io.Exception: Cannot run program "file:/C:/Users/Joe/MyProject.jar/resources/phantomjs.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find file specified`

By the way this is my first time asking a question on SO, so if you need additional info or have any suggestions or comments on phrasing comment with some feedback. Thank You!

**UPDATE** 
After some more searching I found that an executable could not be executed from within the jar. I have created a method to copy the executable to outside the jar which seems to work.

```
private static String loadPhantomJS() {
    String phantomJs = "phantomjs.exe";
    try {
        InputStream in = WebShot.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/phantomjs/" + phantomJs);
        File fileOut = new File(storePath + phantomJs);
        OutputStream out = FileUtils.openOutputStream(fileOut);
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        in.close();
        out.close();
        return fileOut.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

please note that this method only works for windows machines, change the file path for linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above method works for Windows machines, note though that any file you want to run must also exist unpacked, outside the jar file. A similar method to `loadPhantomJS` can be used to unpack other resource files from the jar file. I used this method:

```
private static void makeLocalFile(String outPath, InputStream is) {
    try {
        InputStream is;
        File fileOut = new File(outPath);
        OutputStream out;
        out = FileUtils.openOutputStream(fileOut);
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I get an `InputStream` from my resources using, `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("jsFile.js")`. The only way I was able to get it to work so far on linux is by actually installing `phantomjs` the linux instillation first. Will update this answer if/when I find a better solution.